# read/write process memory when sudo has no permission to do so

Tags: python, linux, memory, process

I have a short python script, which is reading memory of other process. When I am going through the maps, I can see that some pieces of the memory don't give me read/write permissions. That is true even when I run the script with sudo. Is there any way to get these permissions? I am using newest Ubuntu and code in python3. The code I use is shown below.

```
import re
import sys

def search(number,chunk):
    for bit in chunk:
        if bit == number:
            print("Hit!: " + str(number))
            
def search16bits(number, chunk):
    length = len(chunk)/8
    #print("Length: " + str(length))
    num = int(length/2)
    #print(chunk[int(num/8)-1])
    #for i in range(num):
        #print(i)
    for i in range(num - 1):
        start = num
        second = start + 1
        result = chunk[second] + 256 * chunk[start]
        #print(result)
        if number == result:
            print("Hit!: " + str(number))
            exit()
        

def print_memory_of_pid(pid, only_writable=True):
    """ 
    Run as root, take an integer PID and return the contents of memory to STDOUT
    """
    memory_permissions = 'rw' if only_writable else 'r-'
    sys.stderr.write("PID = %d" % pid)
    with open("/proc/%d/maps" % pid, 'r') as maps_file:
        with open("/proc/%d/mem" % pid, 'rb') as mem_file:
            for line in maps_file.readlines():  # for each mapped region
                m = re.match(r'([0-9A-Fa-f]+)-([0-9A-Fa-f]+) ([-r][-w])', line)
                #print("m:" + str(m))
                if m.group(3) == memory_permissions: 
                    #sys.stderr.write("\nOK : \n" + line+"\n")
                    start = int(m.group(1), 16)
                    if start > 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF:
                        continue
                    end = int(m.group(2), 16)
                    sys.stderr.write( "start = " + str(start) + "\n")
                    mem_file.seek(start)  # seek to region start
                    chunk = mem_file.read(end - start)  # read region contents
                    #print()
                    #print()
                    print("###########################Next Chunk:######################################")
                    #search16bits(221, chunk)
                    #print(len(chunk))
                    #print(chunk)  # dump contents to standard output
                else:
                    print("No permission")
                    #sys.stderr.write("\nPASS : \n" + line+"\n")

if __name__ == '__main__': # Execute this code when run from the commandline.
    try:
        assert len(sys.argv) == 2, "Provide exactly 1 PID (process ID)"
        pid = int(sys.argv[1])
        print_memory_of_pid(pid)
    except (AssertionError, ValueError) as e:
        print("Please provide 1 PID as a commandline argument.")
        print("You entered: %s" + str(sys.argv))
        raise e
```

Comment: Your question does not seem to be related to coding but to the security features of your OS.

Comment: So is it not a good place to ask the question? Do you know about any better place?